# Assign different wifi network to different adapter

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I am using desktop computer with Ubuntu 14.04. My computer has 2 wifi adapter, via PCI and USB, let say named `dongle_a` and `dongle_b`, I need to use those two to connect to 2 networks, let say named `network_x` and `network_y`

My question is, how to assign these networks, so when I start the pc, then `dongle_a` automatically connect to `network_x`, and `dongle_b` automatically connect to `network_y` ?

Currently I have to manually connect those dongle to my desired network, because they both connect to the same network on startup.

As additional info, I am using `gnome-panel` instead of `unity`. The wifi card is `qualcomm` and `mediatek`

Thank you.

**UPDATE**
as requested, this is the result of `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:d4:35:ae:25:52  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:10052 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10052 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1002518 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:1002518 (1.0 MB)

ra0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:de:27:08:0f:f9  
          inet addr:192.168.36.129  Bcast:192.168.36.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::eade:27ff:fe08:ff9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:162544 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4386 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:32372542 (32.3 MB)  TX bytes:430932 (430.9 KB)

wlan2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:f2:6d:7e:15:6a  
          inet addr:192.168.1.108  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f6f2:6dff:fe7e:156a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:116829 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:99765 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:104209631 (104.2 MB)  TX bytes:14175717 (14.1 MB)
```

The used network adapter is `ra0` and `wlan2`, others can be ignored.